# Multiple records for nested/embedded schema is not getting inserted in mongodb, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I am new to nodejs and mongodb, I have json file with below structure, 
I have defined one shipment schema with the "comments" section as nested schema

```
{
    "buyerId": "B58",
    "sellerId": "SL8",
    "comments": {
        "title": "title5",
        "body": "body5",
        "date": "12-07-2017"
    }
}
```

I have defined one function like below

```
exports.post = function(req, res) {
    const comments = []
    var s = new shipment();
    s.sellerId = req.body.sellerId;
    s.buyerId = req.body.buyerId;
    s.poId = req.body.poId;
    s.comments.push({
        title: req.body.comments.title,
        body: req.body.comments.body,
        date: req.body.comments.date
    });

    s.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log("added");
        res.send({
            message: 'shipment Created !'
        })
    })
}
```

The above 'post' function will work properly  when I have only one "comments" section, I mean the data gets properly 
inserted into the mongodb as shown below

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59689bc59058dbc812000002"),
    "buyerId": "B58",
    "sellerId": "SL8",
    "comments": [{
        "title": "title5",
        "body": "body5",
        "date": ISODate("2017-12-06T18:30:00Z"),
        "_id": ObjectId("59689bc59058dbc812000003")
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

but when I have multiple "comments" section as shown below,

```
{
    "buyerId": "B58",
    "sellerId": "SL8",
    "comments": [{
            "title": "title5",
            "body": "body5",
            "date": "12-07-2017"
        },
        {
            "title": "title8",
            "body": "body7",
            "date": "12-07-2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

then no comments section gets inserted into the mongodb as shown below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5968c04d4c02336800000002"),
    "buyerId": "B57",
    "sellerId": "SL7",
    "comments": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("5968c04d4c02336800000003")
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

what changes should I do in the function to get all the comments section being inserted into the mongodb properly ?

Comment: Show your actual schema because it appears to be actually "referenced" rather than "embedded" as you point to at the start of your question. You should also research those terms and understand what the difference is and means. Is the second example actually representative of the data being sent in the POST request? Because note here that in the first the content is not an array and is therefore okay to `.push()` because it's a single element. The second form "is an array", which of course you cannot `.push()` without iterating the elements.

Comment: But in all other reality, you really need to read about the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator in the core documentation. Which is vastly superior to what you are presently doing.

Answer (score 0):

originally comments is an array in the second example comments is an array. 
your function

```
s.comments.push({
    title: req.body.comments.title,
    body: req.body.comments.body,
    date: req.body.comments.date
})
```

will only work if comments is an object. Put that in a for loop to make it work with arrays like so

```
for( var i = 0; i < req.body.comments.length; i++){
    s.comments.push({ 
        title: req.body.comments[i].title,
        body: req.body.comments[i].body,
        date: req.body.comments[i].date
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, i did little modification for your hint and it worked, i  changed the code like                                                                                  for( var i = 0; i < req.body.comments.length; i++){
  s.comments.push({ title: req.body.comments[i].title, body : req.body.comments[i].body, date : req.body.comments[i].date  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning value of every property, make instance and pass body directly into it.

```
const s = new shipment(req.body)
```

And then when you send data to the request, send in the following format

{ `"buyerId": "B58", "sellerId": "SL8", "comments": [{ "title": "title5", "body": "body5", "date": "12-07-2017" }, { "title": "title8", "body": "body7", "date": "12-07-2017" } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below and it worked.

```
for( var i = 0; i < req.body.comments.length; i++){
s.comments.push(
{ title: req.body.comments[i].title, 
body : req.body.comments[i].body, 
date : req.body.comments[i].date  });
}
```